# react-loadable higher order component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-loadable

I'm trying to use [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) to implement code splitting, and as suggested in the docs I've created a HOC for it, like this:

```
export default function({ componentPath }) {
  return Loadable({
    loader: async () => {      
      const component = await import(componentPath)
      return component;
    },  
    delay: 200
  });
}
```

and I use it like this

```
import withLoadable from "hoc/withLoadable";

....

const Home = withLoadable({componentPath: "containers/Home"});
```

but I got the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'containers/Home'
    at eval (eval at ./src/hoc lazy recursive (main.chunk.js:formatted:98), <anonymous>:5:11)
```

Referring to the docs [here](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#how-do-i-avoid-repetition), they mentioned this issue and how to solve it, I tried to add the `modules`, and `webpack` attributes but it didn't work.

BTW: in webpack.config.js I've added the "src" directory to the resolve modules like this:

```
...
resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
      modules: ['src','node_modules'].concat(
        // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
        process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
      ),
...
```

I'm sure I miss something, but I can get it ...